# How do I find out which partition is my *nix installed on?

Tags: partitioning

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3b7e273f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   266242047   133017600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       266242048   976771071   355264512    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

How can I find out which of the above partitions is my linux distribution installed on?

Note: I'm running Ubuntu and I installed it with Wubi. I did read this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35950/how-to-determine-the-partition-on-which-ubuntu-is-installed-and-resize-it) but the answers don't seem so clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> WUBI ... installs the software on an existing Windows partition, 
>   thus without need for partitioning. ...
>   Ubuntu is installed within a file in the Windows file system (c:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk), ...
>   Wubi also creates a swap file in the Windows file system (c:\ubuntu\disks\swap.disk),

says [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_(Ubuntu_installer))